# Projectivities of line $\mathbb{P_1}$ over $\mathbb{Z/2Z}$ field

Tags: geometry, solution-verification, projective-space, projection

Let the projective line $\mathbb{P_1}$ over the field of $\mathbb{Z/2Z}$. I'm asked to prove there are 6 projectivities between $\mathbb{P_1} \longrightarrow \mathbb{P_1}$ and giving the equations.

This is what I thought about it. As long as there is 2 classes in $\mathbb{Z/2Z}$ and four points to determine the projectivity, we can combine them in 7 ways, acording to the condition $ad - bc \neq 0$: $(0,1,1,1)$ ,$(1,0,1,1)$, $(1,1,0,1)$, $(1,1,1,0)$, $(0,1,1,0)$, $(1,0,0,1)$. Because if we take $(1,1,1,1)$:

$$z \rightarrow \frac{z+1}{z+1} = 1$$
which is no line. Actually, all equations goes by:

$$z \rightarrow \frac{az+b}{dz+d}$$

I'm not sure to need to prove there are projectivities, that can be done through the double reason.
Is it correct?

Edit:

Let $T: E \longrightarrow E'$ an isomorphism between $\mathbb{K}$- vectorial spaces. The aplication $\hat{T}: \mathbb{P}(E) \longrightarrow \mathbb{P}(E')$ and $\pi: E \longrightarrow \mathbb{P}(E) $, then $\hat{T}$ is projectivity iff $\hat{T}(\pi (e)) = \pi (T(e))$.

Comment: One way to think about this is to observe that there are three points on $\Bbb{P}^1(\Bbb{Z}/2\Bbb{Z})$. You may be used to calling them $0,1$ and $\infty$. Hence there are exactly $3!=6$ ways to permute them. A special property of $\Bbb{Z}/2\Bbb{Z}$ is that all six permutations come from fractional linear transformations $z\mapsto (az+b)/(cz+d)$. For example $z\mapsto 1/z$ maps $1$ to itself and interchanges $0$ and $\infty$. Anyway, there cannot be more than six because of this.

Comment: BTW. I am unfamiliar with your term *projectivity*. Probably something lost in translation. Anyway, I know that all six permutations arise in the prescribed way, and that is the only interpretation of your question fitting the facts (that I can think of).

Comment: Jyrki Lahtonen, I edited to define projectivity. Thank you, yours is undoubtly the answer.